# How to find the indefinite integral of $\arctan((x^2+1)^{1/3})$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

I have to find the indefinite integral of $\arctan((x^2+1)^{1/3})$. I have tried to do different variable substitutions, then integration by parts, but in the end I always got a another integral that I could not calculate. Please give a hint how to calculate this integral.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain but there doesn't seem to be a result for the indefinite integral in terms of standard mathematical functions.

Comment: What do you mean with "have to find"? Many integrals cannot be evaluated  in terms of elementary functions.  This seems to be one of them.

Comment: A CAS says it's a mess of Appell and Elliptic functions. Not likely there is a nice representation in elementary functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change variables $y^3 = 1+x^2$ to get
$$
\int \arctan(\sqrt[3]{x^2+1}) \, dx = \frac{3}{2}\int\frac{y^2\arctan y}{\sqrt{y^3-1}}\;dy
$$
Integrate by parts to get
$$
{\frac {\arctan \left( y \right)  \left( y-1 \right)  \left( {y}^{2}+y
+1 \right) }{\sqrt {{y}^{3}-1}}}-\int \!{\frac { \left( y-1 \right) 
 \left( {y}^{2}+y+1 \right) }{ \left( {y}^{2}+1 \right) \sqrt {{y}^{3}
-1}}}\,{\rm d}y
\\=
{ {\arctan \left( y \right)  \sqrt{ y^3-1 } }}-\int \!{\frac { \sqrt{y^3-1} 
}{  {y}^{2}+1
 }}\,{\rm d}y
$$
That is an elliptic integral.  In Maple it is about a page long,
in terms of $F$ and $\Pi$.

Answer (score 2):

If you do $x=y^3-1$ and $\mathrm dx=3y^2\,\mathrm dy$, then that indefinite integral becomes$$\int3y^2\arctan(y)\,\mathrm dy.$$You can deal with it by integration by parts$$\int3y^2\arctan(y)\,\mathrm dy=y^3\arctan(y)-\int\frac{y^3}{y^2+1}\,\mathrm dy.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Should not it be $x^2=y^3-1$?

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram Alpha says that the result 'cannot be expressed in terms of standard mathematical functions'.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20arctan%28%28x%5E2%2B1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29&assumption=%22%5E%22%20-%3E%20%22Real%22)

The best you can do is say that
$$
\int \arctan(\sqrt[3]{x^2+1}) \, dx = \int_{0}^{x} \arctan(\sqrt[3]{t^2+1}) \, dt+C \, .
$$
This result follows directly from the fundamental theorem of calculus.